# Organising ties in closet

Tags: clothing, organization

For years I have had my ties hanging on an ordinary clothes hanger. However from time to time they either fall down, or is collated on the end and it's a mess. And they are hard to separate, get an overview and pick one.

Therefore I ask you for a hack in how to store ties in a better way with the following specifications:

- around 10-20 ties
- keep them organised, and still be able to pick a single tie without disturbing the rest
- take a minimum of space
- (optional) possible to hang alongside shirts

Do note that I don't use ties very often, so I don't need the solution to be extremely accessible, and I'll survive using a little bit of time to get it back into the system.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a **tie rack** or make your own. The core concept is pretty simple: instead of hanging your ties on a line (like a clothes hanger), hang them in a grid.

Here's an example of one that is commercially available:

[image]

If you don't want to buy one, *you are still in luck*. As I said, the idea is pretty simple, and it's pretty easy to make your own.

Use any grid-like object you have lying around, whether it is a toaster oven rack or a section of chain-link fence or a wire storage grid square. I recommend the last one in particular. If you want to hang it with the rest of your clothes, you can tie or glue it to a hanger.

[image]

Comment: This thing is magic

Comment: These things don't work for more than a few days because ties have very low friction.  After a week of sliding hangers around, the ties slip bit by bit until one side is heavier and it falls off.  A clothespin helps but it can permanently deform the tie.

Answer (score 6):

If you've got drawer space, roll 'em up and store them as demonstrated here

https://effortlessgent.com/how-to-store-pocket-squares-ties-belts-cufflinks-accessories/

There's a link within that link to a compartment separator to hold such things as rolled up ties, belts and the like, but Ikea sells those too.

Comment: Rolling your ties also helps to remove the creases from tying them, more than hanging does, in my experience.

Comment: Yep, rolling's brilliant, I roll everything when packing to go away, far fewer creases that way...

Answer (score 2):

I have always found it harder to hang up a tie on a rod in a closet than on a doorknob, or a simple wall hook. But I only own 3 or 4 ties. 5 to 10 wall hooks might take up a bit more space.

When I do put a tie on a closet rod, I loop it once (loose tie) to keep it in place so it does not fall... Much better than hanging loosely.

Comment: If you have lots of ties, you can put a coat rack on your wall instead of a bunch of individual wall hooks.